# Refactoring Java 8 stream code

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have implemented the following code using Java 8.

```
Map<String, String> coMap = getHashMap();

String newCoName = coMap.entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(coEntry -> coEntry.getValue().equals(newcoId))
                     .map(coEntry -> coEntry.getKey())
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());


String oldCoName = coMap.entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(coEntry -> coEntry.getValue().equals(oldcoId))
                     .map(coEntry -> coEntry.getKey())
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Now. I want to know any better way of doing this instead of repeating the same lines of code twice.

Comment: Like a method? or a for loop?

Comment: put the code in a method passing the coId as argument: `getCoName(String coId)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the whole difference is an id, a simple method does that for you.

```
String getName(int id) { // supposed id is an integer
    return coMap.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .filter(coEntry -> coEntry.getValue().equals(id))
             .map(coEntry -> coEntry.getKey())
             .collect(Collectors.joining()); 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

A bigger issue than repeating the same code twice is executing the same code twice.

It would be more efficient to run a single `Stream` pipeline to produce your output :

```
Map<String,String> keysByValue =
            coMap.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                                   Collectors.joining())));
```

This would give you for each value of your original `Map` (not only the two values your original code is searching for), the joint keys having that value.

Then you can extract from the `Map` the data you need :

```
String newCoName = keysByValue.get(newcoId);
String oldCoName = keysByValue.get(oldcoId);
```

Sample input and output :

```
Map<String,String> coMap = new HashMap<> ();
coMap.put("a","foo");
coMap.put("b","foo");
coMap.put("c","bar");
coMap.put("d","bar");
Map<String,String> keysByValue = ... // same as the code above
String newValueKeys = keysByValue.get("foo");
String oldValueKeys = keysByValue.get("bar");
System.out.println (newValueKeys);
System.out.println (oldValueKeys);
```

Output :

```
ab
cd
```

Comment: It’s not clear whether there can be other values, besides `newcoId` and `oldcoId`. If so, a `filter` step letting only these two values pass can avoid doing unnecessary work. If we assume that there are only the two values (or using the `filter` step), we could also use `partitioningBy` instead of `groupingBy`.

Comment: @Holger I figured it would be useful to produce a Map with all the values of the original Map as keys, but that would depend on the actual usage - i.e. whether we can produce this Map once and keep re-using it for different pairs of values, or we have to produce it every time the original Map is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Other way uses with FunctionalInterface `Predicate`, your condition filter will be dynamic

```
public static Predicate<Map.Entry> getPredicate(String col) {
    return p -> p.getValue().equals(col);
}

public static String getName(HashMap<String, String> coMap, Predicate<Map.Entry> predicate) {
    return coMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(predicate)
            .map(coEntry -> coEntry.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Calling in your code:

```
  getName(coMap, getPredicate(newcoId));
  getName(coMap, getPredicate(oldcoId));
```

Answer (score 0):

most IDE's can refactor it for you using "Extract Method" refactoring:
http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html
or you can do it by hand

Answer (score 0):

You may use this helper method:

```
public static String join(Map<String, String> map, String value) {
    return map.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> Objects.equals(map.get(key), value))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Here some example code using the method:

```
    Map<String, String> coMap = new HashMap<>();
    coMap.put("A", null);
    coMap.put("B", "V");
    coMap.put("C", "V");
    coMap.put("D", "Z");
    coMap.put("E", "Z");
    coMap.put("F", null);

    System.out.println("Vs: " + join(coMap, "V"));
    System.out.println("Zs: " + join(coMap, "Z"));
```

And here the output:

```
Vs: BC
Zs: DE
```

Comment: Is there a reason for removing `.map(coEntry -> coEntry.getKey())`?

Comment: You are interessted in the keys right? Hence this algorithm saves you from mapping your Map.Entrys to keys. Thats all. I added null-safe comparison in case the value is null.

Comment: *"You are interessted in the keys right?"* No, I'm not.

Comment: But you are finally joining the keys with `.collect(Collectors.joining())` to a String

Comment: No I'm not. How about re-checking if you're writing with OP or not? ;P

Comment: I am sorry, but what I see is: keep map-entries which are equal to a given value, map the map-entries to their keys, join the keys to a string. What did I miss?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131231/discussion-between-harmlezz-and-tom).

Comment: *"What did I miss?"* You missed that I'm not OP. I asked, you answered. Case closed. No need to assume what **I** might do, because I don't do anything here ;P.

Comment: Well, streaming over the keys only, saves you from the cheap `Entry.getKey()` call and introduces an expensive `map.get` call. The dealing with `Optional` makes the code even worse. You can simply use [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) to check two objects for equality in a `null`-safe way.